# How to have servlet context-path but it should not reflect for actuator path

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have following configuration

```yaml
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /product-management

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health,info,metrics
      base-path: /actuator
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
    info:
      enabled: true
```

But when I want to access the actuator, it should exclude the context-path. Ex: Actuator should be accessed at http://localhost:8080/actuator/health and not at http://localhost:8080/product-management/actuator/health

I want this because, we have readiness and liveness probes configured in kubernetes where we had to explicitly modify the probe urls from /actuator/health to product-management/actuator/health. So to avoid this how can I still ensure actuator is working with only /actuator/health instead of product-management/actuator/health so that the probes work as expected. Thanks in advance

Comment: `server.servlet.context-path` will influence anything you do, that is the whole point of that property. If you want `base-path` to take effect you need to configure it on a different port else it won't work (this is also stated in the information for said property). Instead of `server.servlet.context-path` try `spring.mvc.servlet.path` instead of `server.servlet.context-path`. That being said it might not work as everything runs on the same endpoint eventually.

Comment: We use different ports for management and api, 8080 and 9090 for example. That helps to avoid context path in actuator uris. Ask if you need in more details, but that "workaround" really works